# Hide users with a specific role from users list on WordPress admin dashboard

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have two roles called Agent and Subagent.
I want to hide these two specific roles from the admin user list.

I tried using the `pre_user_query` filter but couldn't get it to work.

Could anyone please suggest a correct way to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Possibly you can get idea from this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922108/hide-a-particular-admin-account-from-wordpress-user-list

Comment: ^^ just switch implement the role instead of username.

Comment: I have to do the same like there are 5 users with role "agent" So, I want to hide those users from user list.

Comment: @nir this is for hiding admin when admin is logged in. I want to hide users have role "agent" and "subagent" from users list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the perfect solution for what I wanted here: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/pre_user_query.html

```
add_action('pre_user_query','hide_all_agents_subagents');

function hide_all_agents_subagents( $u_query ) {
    
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( $current_user->roles[0] != 'administrator' ) { 
        global $wpdb;
        $u_query->query_where = str_replace(
            'WHERE 1=1', 
            "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
                SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
                    WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities'
                    AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value NOT LIKE '%agent%' AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value NOT LIKE '%subagent%')", 
            $u_query->query_where
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much this is what i was looking for. :)

Comment: Hello @armanH, hope it helped you. don't forget to upvote the answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Simpler & safer:

```php
add_filter('pre_get_users', function ($user_query) {
  // use the sluglike role names, not their "display_name"s 
  $user_query->set('role__not_in', ['agent', 'subagent']);
});
```

[`role__not_in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/#user-role-parameter) available since WP 4.4.

Caveat: the roles (and their user count) will still show up above the users table.

Comment: Thanks @kubi for the solution.

Comment: This will remove users with specified roles from **ALL** user queries not only the admin dashboard users list.

Comment: @CodeSpirit you are right, it was merely a better version of OP's already-accepted self-answer (which has the same flaw), so should have been a comment, I guess.